# Laravel 7 loginUsingId not persisting / causing log out

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I am trying to create a "Shadow" user feature, it's basically just to allow admins to log in as another user to use the system as the "shadowed user" would.

I've used `Auth::loginUsingId` before but i can't figure out why the below isn't working.

```
public function shadowUser($id, Request $request){
    
    $user = User::query()->find($id);
    $previousUserId = $request->user()->id;

    Session()->flush();
    Session()->put('shadow.user.id', $previousUserId);

    $shadowedUser = Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    dump(Auth::check());
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

If I dump out the `$shadowedUser` it shows the correct user and the `Auth::check()` returns true.

I have also tried these but they made no difference: `Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);`, `Auth::guard($guard)->loginUsingId($user->ID);` and `Auth::login($user, true);`

There's no crazy middleware just laravel's defaults.

I've tried a few things like removing the session flush but it always just logs me out.

Comment: there is a handy package to do this already if you don't want to write it all https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate

Comment: You should try `Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);` or `Auth::login($user, true);`

Comment: @jewishmoses i've tried that also! i'll add that to my question!

Comment: Looking at the ready made package, they logout the current user before logging in the shadow user. Even if you aren't going to use the package you can inspect it to see how it is done. The file with the code you are after is https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate/blob/master/src/Services/ImpersonateManager.php function is called `take`

Comment: @Rooneyl I've tried logging the current user out also and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that Laravel sessions are a bit funky in this scenario, it looks like you're trying to log someone in when the session is already active, log the current user out, flush the session then log in the new user, this way it will tell Laravel that this is a new user signing in and reset the session.

In your script, once you've logged the user out, flushed the session and logged the new user in, add the previous users id to the new session otherwise it will get deleted then you'll be able to see the previous user who was logged in, or the person shadowing you in this case.

```
public function shadowUser($id, Request $request){
    
    $user = User::query()->find($id);
    $previousUserId = $request->user()->id;

    Auth::logout($guard);

    Session()->flush();

    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    Session()->put('shadow.user.id', $previousUserId);

    dump(Auth::check());
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick after i took out the dump! thanks!